# Why are the syllables in "elephant" divided in two different ways?

Tags: pronunciation, dictionaries, phonology, syllables

When I'm using Merriam-Webster dictionary to confirm the pronunciation and I found out that the syllables divided in the word and its phonetic are different.

For example, [elephant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elephant),  and [experience](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/experience).

- Elephant is divided into **el-e-phant** which the l is the ending sound of the first syllable, but its phonetic is divided as \ **ˈe-lə-fənt** \ which the l sound goes the second syllable as the beginning sound.
- Experience is divided into **ex-pe-ri-ence** and the letter r is pronounced as a consonant, but its phonetic is divided as \ **ik-ˈspir-ē-ən(t)s**\ which the r sound goes to the second syllable, and make an r-controlled vowel sound with the letter e.

How would this happen? I'm totally confused. I really need your kind explanation or some useful material for reference.

Comment: Pronunciation varies from region to region and person to person.  What's in the dictionary will always be, at best, an approximation.   Or it might just be a misprint.  It seems wrong to me too.

Comment: @HenryWang Be careful with the notations. (Each dictionary may use its own notations.) Merriam-Webster uses el·e·phant for written syllabification (i.e., hyphenation), and \ˈe-lə-fənt\ for spoken syllabification. One is for the eye, the other is for the ear.

Comment: To divide words into sounds is called writing them phonetically or phonemically. A phoneme is the smallest unit of sound without meaning  in a language and contrasts with other ones. There is a phonetic and phonemic alphabet (44 separate sounds) in English. You have to learn it in order to understand how e-le-phant becomes ɛlɪfənt (phonemic writing using phonetic notation). Elephant is three syllables but seven phonemes (seven different units of sound).

Answer (score 2):

It's a common misunderstanding to think that the way a dictionary divides headwords is supposed to indicate the syllabification of the word. It doesn't; it's related to the syllabification, but not the same. What it's meant to indicate is where a word can be broken for hyphenation.

You can find more explanation of this in the answer to the following ELU question: [Different syllabic boundaries in various dictionaries?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21529/different-syllabic-boundaries-in-various-dictionaries)

Actual phonetic syllabification is also complicated. Certain words are easy to divide into syllables (e.g. "hangnail" should clearly be divided as /hæŋ.neɪl/) but many others are more difficult. Different scholars have different theories about how to divide words like "barrel", "mattress", "later" and "selfish". [John Wells](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/syllabif.htm) proposed syllabifying these as /bær.əl/, /mætr.əs/, /leɪt.ə/ and /sɛlf.ɪʃ/ respectively.

Comment: As a footnote, I think el-e-phant and e-le-phant would end up sounding pretty much the same either way – a phenomenon responsible for many misheard lyrics.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a paper version Merriam-Webster dictionary, and it explains the difference between the dot division and the hyphen division as this:

> "A hyphen is used in the pronunciation to show syllabic division.
>   these hyphens sometimes coincide with the centered dots in the entry
>   word that indicate end-of-line division:
>
> **ab·sen·tee** \ˌab-sən-ˈtē\
>
> Sometimes they do not:
>
> **met·ric** \ˈme-trik\

So, the syllabic division of elephant and experience should be divided into e-le-phant \ˈe-lə-fənt\ and ex-per-i-ence \ik-ˈspir-ē-ən(t)s. My new concern is that the pronunciation of exp**er**ience \ik-ˈsp**ir**-ē-ən(t)s. The letter combination **er** in the word entry is pronounced as /ir/ which is an R-controlled vowel sound. From the syllabic division, /ir/ should have same pronunciation as word ear. But, it seems that people pronounce the word as \ik-ˈspi-rē-ən(t)s\, the /ir/ sound was separated into a vowel /i/ and a consonant /r/ which links with the vowel /i/ after it but not the vowel /i/ in front of it. Is that right?

Comment: Nice find! As to your question at the end of your answer, I think it's probably worth writing a new question. FWIW, in English, phonemes are pronounced consecutively, so that /r/ is linked to both /i/ before it and /ē/ after it. So, unlike syllables in some other languages, the four syllables, \ik-ˈspir-ē-ən(t)s\, are not pronounced separately (i.e., without linking between syllables). One possible argument for grouping /r/ with /spir/ is that if we ask a speaker to pronounce the first two syllables of *experience*, chances are, they will pronounce \ik-ˈspir\, rather than \ik-ˈspi\.